# Как внести данные в диаграмму из таблицы

Tags: javascript, chart.js

у меня есть диаграмма на Chatr.js. В data лежит значение количества. Как сделать так, чтоб это значение бралось из таблицы?

Изначально есть 1 таблица, вторая таблица создается из первой, а из второй таблицы уже формируется диаграмма.

Диаграмма должна быть примерно такая(здесь она не правильная):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Для удобства:
https://codepen.io/kapets666/pen/rNRoeLR

Сам код:

```
<body>
  <h2>Фильтр заявок</h2>

  <input type="text" id="mashine" placeholder="Введите номер станка">
  <input type="text" id="priority" placeholder="Введите приоритет заявки">
  <input type="text" id="plot" placeholder="Введите Участок">
  <button onclick="filterTable()">Фильтровать</button>

  <table id="requests" border="1">
    <caption>Таблица заявок</caption>
    <tr>
      <th>Инвентарный номер станка</th>
      <th>Приоритет заявки</th>
      <th>Участок</th>
      <th>Дата создания заявки</th>
      <th>Дата закрытия заявки</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Красная</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2024-01-01</td>
      <td>2024-05-01</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Красная</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2024-01-01</td>
      <td>2024-05-01</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Зеленая</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>2024-01-01</td>
      <td>2024-05-02</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Зеленая</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>2024-02-01</td>
      <td>2024-02-01</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>Серая</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>2024-02-02</td>
      <td>2024-06-02</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <label for="fromDate">От:</label>
  <input type="date" id="fromDate">
  <label for="toDate">До:</label>
  <input type="date" id="toDate">
  <button onclick="filterRequests()">Отфильтровать</button>
  <br><br>

  <table id="filteredRequests" border="1">
    <caption>Таблица отфильтрованных заявок</caption>
  </table>

  <div class="container">
    <canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
  </div>

  <script src="node_modules/chart.js/dist/chart.js"></script>
  <script src="node_modules/chart.js/dist/chart.umd.js"></script>
  <script src="main.js"></script>
 
</body>
```

```
function filterTable() {
  var inputMashine = document.getElementById("mashine").value.toUpperCase();
  var inputPriority = document.getElementById("priority").value.toUpperCase();
  var inputPlot = document.getElementById("plot").value.toUpperCase();
  var table = document.getElementById("requests");
  var tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

  for (var i = 1; i < tr.length; i++) {
    var tdMashine = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
    var tdPriority = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[1];
    var tdPlot = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[2];
    if (tdMashine && tdPriority && tdPlot) {
      var mashine = tdMashine.textContent.toUpperCase();
      var priority = tdPriority.textContent.toUpperCase();
      var plot = tdPlot.textContent.toUpperCase();
      if (mashine.includes(inputMashine) && priority.includes(inputPriority) && plot.includes(inputPlot)) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  }
}


function filterRequests() {

  var inputMashine = document.getElementById("mashine").value.toUpperCase();
  var inputPriority = document.getElementById("priority").value.toUpperCase();
  var inputPlot = document.getElementById("plot").value.toUpperCase();
  var table = document.getElementById("requests");
  var tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");




  var fromDate = document.getElementById("fromDate").value;
  var toDate = document.getElementById("toDate").value;
  var requests = document.getElementById("requests");
  var filteredRequests = document.getElementById("filteredRequests");

  var rows = requests.rows;
  var filteredRows = [];

  var filteredRowsTwo = [];



  for (var i = 1; i < tr.length; i++) {
    var tdMashine = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
    var tdPriority = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[1];
    var tdPlot = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[2];
    if (tdMashine && tdPriority && tdPlot) {
      var mashine = tdMashine.textContent.toUpperCase();
      var priority = tdPriority.textContent.toUpperCase();
      var plot = tdPlot.textContent.toUpperCase();
      if (mashine.includes(inputMashine) && priority.includes(inputPriority) && plot.includes(inputPlot)) {
        filteredRowsTwo.push(rows[i]);
      }
    }
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < filteredRowsTwo.length; i++) {
    var date = filteredRowsTwo[i].cells[3].innerHTML;
    if (date >= fromDate && date <= toDate) {
      filteredRows.push(filteredRowsTwo[i]);
    }
  }

  filteredRequests.innerHTML = '<tr><th>Дата</th><th>Вид заявки</th><th>Количество заявок</th></tr>';

  var counts = {};
  for (var i = 0; i < filteredRows.length; i++) {
    var date = filteredRows[i].cells[3].innerHTML;
    var requestType = filteredRows[i].cells[1].innerHTML;
    counts[date + requestType] = (counts[date + requestType] || 0) + 1;
  }

  for (var key in counts) {
    var date = key.substring(0, 10);
    var requestType = key.substring(10);
    filteredRequests.innerHTML += '<tr><td>' + date + '</td><td>' + requestType + '</td><td>' + counts[key] + '</td></tr>';

    let valuesArray = [];

    if (requestType.includes('красный')) {
      // Добавление значения третьей ячейки в массив
      valuesArray.push(counts[key]);
    }
    console.log(valuesArray);
  }


  // var dataRed = [];
  // var dataGrean = [];
  // var dataElow = [];
  // var tableRow = table.filteredRequests("tr");

  // for (var i = 1; i < tableRow.length; i++) {

  //   var cells = tableRow[i].getElementsByTagName("td");

  //   for (var j=0; j<cells.length; j++){
  //     if (cells[j].innerHTML.includes("Красная")) {
  //       console.log("ZBS");
  //     }
  //   }
  // }


}

const labels = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('#data-table tbody td:first-child')).map(e => e.textContent);
const data = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('#data-table tbody td:last-child')).map(e => +e.textContent);


new Chart(document.getElementById('myChart'), {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: labels,
    datasets: [{
      label: 'Data',
      data: data,
      backgroundColor: "red",
    },

    {
      label: 'Data',
      data: data,
      backgroundColor: "green",
    },
    {
      label: 'Data',
      data: data,
      backgroundColor: "blue",
    }],
  },
  options: {
    plugins: {
      title: {
        display: true,
        text: 'Stacked Bar chart for pollution status'
      },
    },
    scales: {
      x: {
        stacked: true,
      },
      y: {
        stacked: true
      }
    }
  }
});
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `Как сделать так, чтоб это значение бралось из таблицы HTML? ` -- написать код, который будет использовать данные таблицы, в Chart.JS

Comment: @ΝNL993, вау, это гениально, как я сама не дагодалась, в вопросе сказано, чтоя я не понимаю как правильно написать этот код, а когда пытаюсь сделать, основываясь на своих знаниях, то у меня не получается, вот и прошу помоч, спасибо

Comment: Хорошо, давайте так, вы опубликуете свою попытку решения (пусть даже неправильную), а я вам помогу решить задачу.

Comment: @ΝNL993, Хорошо, я исправила вопрос, спасибо

Comment: Значит, что вам нужно сделать, так это засунуть код chart.js'а в конец функции `filterRequests` (вместе с переменной `labels`), дальше создать переменные для каждого цвета (как вы и сделали в закомментированном коде), ну и потом нужно будет пушить в соответствующий массив, если цвет совпадает. А в самом chart'e мы должны записать для каждого цвета свою переменную: `{ label: 'Data', data: dataRed, backgroundColor: 'red' } // и т.д.`. лэйблы по идее можно оставить как есть.

Comment: @ΝNL993 я в кодпент обнавила, у меня что-то не получается, красный столб не получится https://i.stack.imgur.com/DlAap.png